# How many queries per second execute in postgressql database

Tags: postgresql, query, execution

I have to monitor database statistic for postgresql and need display as graph.
How to check Query execution time and number of query per seconds in postgres.
What functions available to  get those output??
Any reference site will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are many statistics available, check the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html).